# Loading nine-patch image as a Libgdx Scene2d Button background looks awful

Tags: java, libgdx, nine-patch

I'm trying to use a [Nine Patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) as a background for a Libgdx Scene2d UI button.  It is loading, buts it is really ugly. I can see the "meta-data" pixels, and its being stretched as if it were just a regular image (the text on the button is "Continue"):

[image: ugly image of a nine-patch button]

I'm loading the `.9.png` files directly into a (libgdx) [`NinePatchDrawable`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/NinePatchDrawable.html) via a (libgdx) [`NinePatch`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/NinePatch.html) like this:

```
this.dialogButtonUp = new NinePatchDrawable(
   new NinePatch(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/button-round.9.png"))));
this.dialogButtonDown  = new NinePatchDrawable(
   new NinePatch(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/button-round-down.9.png"))));
```

Then I make a `TextButtonStyle` that describes the button, and references the two `NinePatch` drawables:

```
TextButton.TextButtonStyle buttonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
buttonStyle.font =  aValidFontReally;
buttonStyle.fontColor = Color.BLACK;
buttonStyle.up = this.dialogButtonUp;
buttonStyle.down = this.dialogButtonDown;
buttonStyle.pressedOffsetX = -2;
```

I'm building the button indirectly, via a `Dialog` box:

```
new Dialog( ... ).button("Continue", null, buttonStyle);
```

I've checked the `.9.png` files to make sure that:

- that the asset files were refreshed in Eclipse
- that the meta-data border pixels are either fully-invisible or fully-visible-black
- that the Android `draw9patch` tool can load the images and verify them

Any other suggestions on what to check or change?

Comment: Try drawing each NinePatch with a SpriteBatch using NinePatch.draw() as that will at least isolate where the problem is, ie, if it works then the problem isn't the NinePatch.

Comment: Good point!  I just tried it and also see the same ugliness with a direct `NinePatch.draw(...)`.  So the `Dialog` and `Button` are not botching it.

Comment: Looking at the NinePatch source (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/NinePatch.java) I don't think it does much if you use the constructor that takes a single Texture parameter. Try this constructor instead: public NinePatch (Texture texture, int left, int right, int top, int bottom)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there are "pre-processed" (i.e., ".9.png") and "post-processed" ninepatch textures, and `NinePatch` is for the post-processed ones.  Creating a `TextureAtlas` looks like it will do the processing.  I don't see any run-time support for ".9.png", but maybe I'm not looking in the right place yet ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to some pointers from @RodHyde, it looks like the libgdx `NinePatch` class is designed to accept a "post-processed" nine patch texture (i.e., with separate integer values that describe how to cut the single texture into patches).  This "processing" usually happens as a side-effect of packing a ".9.png" file into a `TextureAtlas` (see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#ninePatches).  A texture atlas is a really good idea (especially when your UI includes a bunch of different texture elements), so this makes sense, but is a bit surprising when developing and trying to get something running.

To work-around this so I can directly include ".9.png" files I wrote this:

```
private static NinePatch processNinePatchFile(String fname) {
    final Texture t = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(fname));
    final int width = t.getWidth() - 2;
    final int height = t.getHeight() - 2;
    return new NinePatch(new TextureRegion(t, 1, 1, width, height), 3, 3, 3, 3);
}
```

This loads the texture, creates a sub-region that trims off the 1-pixel meta-data border, and then just guesses that the nine-patch border elements are 3 pixels wide/tall.  (Computing that correctly by mucking about in the texture data seems possible, but not worth the effort -- just put the texture in an atlas in that case.)

Comment: NinePatch javadoc got improved to make this clearer: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/5ce8dc04153234c760b3753fe3a6b4e6fe1653ea#gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/NinePatch.java