# libgdx TextureAtlas, and NinePatch's

Tags: libgdx, nine-patch

I am making a simple game using libgdx.  I have a TextureAtlas that has I ninepatch I am trying to use: [image: 9patch I wanna use]

The image is saved as menu.9.png

I am using the following code:

```
Image bg = new Image(Room.iAtlas.findRegion("GUI/menu"));
bg.setBounds(guix-border,guiy-border,(border+radius)*2,(border+radius)*2);
batch.begin();
    bg.draw(s,1);
batch.end();
```

The output is like this:
[image]

I really just have no idea what I am doing wrong, but it should be more like this(Except it would have the shapes on top of it, but I didn't add those):
[image]
(I created that by hand, i've never actually had 9patch working, and it doesn't have the ships because I didn't bother to edit those in)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your "nine patch" isn't being treated as a real nine path, and is being treated as a "degenerate" nine patch (I had a very similar problem earlier: [Loading nine-patch image as a Libgdx Scene2d Button background looks awful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355723/loading-nine-patch-image-as-a-libgdx-scene2d-button-background-looks-awful), though I wasn't using a `TextureAtlas` which is supposed to be the solution.)

Basically, when Libgdx reads the nine-patch out of your atlas, its supposed to read all the meta-data that describes how to chop the image up into 9 tiles (see https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/TexturePacker#NinePatches).  I see a couple places this could go wrong:

1. Your texture isn't a valid nine-patch, and the meta-data is being ignored.  (Check with the Android `draw9patch` tool.)
2. Your texture packer isn't processing the `.9.png` file correctly.  Check the contents of the .txt file for your atlas, and see if it has "split" entries associated with the "menu.9.png" entry.
3. The texture lookup is just returning a regular `TextureRegion` wrapper for the nine-patch region, and isn't wrapping it in a `NinePatch` object.  Try using [`TextureRegion.createNinePatch`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html#createPatch(java.lang.String)) to make that more explicit.  (I'm under the impression that this isn't necessary, but maybe it is ...)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'll look into this stuff. Earlier I tried TextureAtlas.createPatch(String name) which is supposed to "get the first NinePatch with that name".

Comment: @csga5000 you should put your comment as a valid answer, it worked for me. Thanks!