# Libgdx Scene2d - Set actor ( TextField ) padding?

Tags: android, user-interface, padding, libgdx, textfield

i have been having trouble setting padding or something similar to an actor. Cant figure out the way. I guess that I must add something in the skin maybe?

I have this TextField:

```
        textboxskin = new Skin();
        textboxskin.add("textfieldback", new Texture("data/textfieldback.png"));
        textboxskin.add("cursor", new Texture("data/cursortextfield.png"));
        textboxskin.add("selection", new Texture("data/selection.png"));
        textboxskin.add("font", font);

        TextFieldStyle textfieldstyle = new TextFieldStyle();
        textfieldstyle.background= textboxskin.getDrawable("textfieldback");
        textfieldstyle.disabledFontColor=Color.BLACK;
        textfieldstyle.font=textboxskin.getFont("font");
        textfieldstyle.fontColor=Color.WHITE;
        textfieldstyle.cursor=textboxskin.getDrawable("cursor");
        textfieldstyle.selection=textboxskin.getDrawable("selection");  


        textfieldusername = new TextField("username", textfieldstyle);
```

which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see it looks horrible left centered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Table class to lay out scene2d UIs. To set up the Table:

```
stage = new Stage();
Table table = new Table();
table.setFillParent(true);
stage.addActor(table);
table.add(textFieldUsername).padBottom(20f); //also use padTop, padLeft, and padRight
table.row();
```

In the main loop, call:

```
stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
stage.draw();
```

For more information on tables, see: http://code.google.com/p/table-layout/

Answer (score 12):

EDIT:
I tried to do the following and it worked in my tests:

```
textfieldstyle.background.setLeftWidth(textfieldstyle.background.getLeftWidth() + 10);
```

---

Searching the libgdx API I couldn't find a way to specify padding for the text inside the TextField component.

As a workaround, yout could copy the original TextField source and create a new TextField, with another name providing a way to implement the padding.

Copy the contents of the libgdx TextField (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextField.java?source=cc)
to another file and call it MyTextField (as an example). Replace the broken TextField references with the new class name.

Create a new variable called paddingLeft, for example:

```
public float paddingLeft = 0.0f;
```

In the draw() method, you can add your padding to the sum to define a new position for the String. Where the code says:

```
font.draw(batch, displayText, x + bgLeftWidth + textOffset, y + textY + yOffset, visibleTextStart, visibleTextEnd);
```

replace with:

```
font.draw(batch, displayText, x + bgLeftWidth + textOffset + leftPadding, y + textY + yOffset, visibleTextStart, visibleTextEnd);
```

(notice the " + leftPadding" in the second code)

Then, if you are using skins, remember to reference your TextField in the uiskin.json file:

```
mypackage.MyTextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: default-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
}
```

and use it in your code:

```
MyTextField txtTest = new MyTextField("Test", skin);
txtTest.leftPadding = 10.0f;
```

This is not the ideal way, but will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a NinePatch. This separates your texture into nine "patches" you define their height and width, and then you give it to a NinePatchDrawable which you can give to a TextButton. I believe the outer "patches" act as margins and with some tweaking (not strenuous) it would look great and accomplish your goals.

I learned about them from this post:
[Loading nine-patch image as a Libgdx Scene2d Button background looks awful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355723/loading-nine-patch-image-as-a-libgdx-scene2d-button-background-looks-awful)